# Get WinAPI's parameters with angr

Tags: angr

First, sorry for my bad english.

I want to make my script to parse PE binary and find some specific API's parameters value automatically.

For example,

```
.text:000000014002DF60 48 89 5C 24 08                                mov     [rsp+arg_0], rbx
.text:000000014002DF65 57                                            push    rdi
.text:000000014002DF66 48 83 EC 20                                   sub     rsp, 20h
.text:000000014002DF6A BA A0 0F 00 00                                mov     edx, 0FA0h      ; dwSpinCount
.text:000000014002DF6F 48 8D 0D DA 92 02 00                          lea     rcx, CriticalSection ; lpCriticalSection
.text:000000014002DF76 FF 15 94 21 00 00                             call    cs:InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount
.text:000000014002DF7C 48 8D 0D 8D 26 00 00                          lea     rcx, ModuleName ; "api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll"
.text:000000014002DF83 FF 15 57 21 00 00                             call    cs:GetModuleHandleW
.text:000000014002DF89 48 8B D8                                      mov     rbx, rax
.text:000000014002DF8C 48 85 C0                                      test    rax, rax
.text:000000014002DF8F 75 15                                         jnz     short loc_14002DFA6
.text:000000014002DF91 48 8D 0D C0 26 00 00                          lea     rcx, aKernel32Dll ; "kernel32.dll"
.text:000000014002DF98 FF 15 42 21 00 00                             call    cs:GetModuleHandleW
```

I arleady get function start address(0x14002DF60) and each GetModuleHandleW call instruction address (0x14002DF83, 0x14002DF98) automatically using Capstone engine.

After that, I want to make my script to find each GetModuleHandleW's parameter (api~~.dll and kernel32.dll).

In first time, I used unicorn emulator to find target API's parameters.
But I cannot assure what other API or branch shows up until reach to the target API.

So, in this case I think I need to use some symbolic execution solution like angr. (yet, I'm not barley understand what symbolic execution extactly are.)

Can I get API's parameters with angr in this case?
and, is there any simillar example that I can test?

I hope for your guide, and happy new year :)